# error while importing observable scrollview lib

Tags: android-studio

I have a sample application in android studio.

I downloaded `observable scrollview` lib from github and imported it to that sample project.

After importing while doing build->make project, getting error:

> **Error:No such property: GROUP for class:
>   org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer**

Then to solve that I removed `apply from: 'gradle-mvn-push.gradle'` from `build.gradle` file of `observablescrollview` sample.

After doing that while again I am trying to bulid the project and get this error:

> **Error:(27, 0) Could not find property 'SYNCED_VERSION_NAME' on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@512ff280.**

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, just type the version like this:

```
compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.5.0'
```

This page can help too: https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView/blob/master/docs/quick-start/dependencies.md